# What are the requirements to be used as a filesystem for MapReduce

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs

I know S3 and some other filesystems can replace HDFS and am wondering what requirements a filesystem needs to meet to be used as a replacement for HDFS in MapReduce framework?

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem must be *distributed* or *globally accessible*, for distributed execution of `MapReduce` to be able to talk to it across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop has an abstract notion of filesystem of which HDFS is just one implementation. The Java abstract class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem represents a filesystem in Hadoop, and there are several concrete implementations implemented including a local for small deployment and/or test purposes.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html